# CSS Always On Top

Tags: html, css, image

I have a website with a fixed image at the top of my screen. When I scroll down my page the image stays at the top like it should. However, all content below overlaps my image and it is then covered.

How do I make my top bar (image) always stay on top? I want it to cover the content of the page as you scroll.

Comment: use the `z-index` style.

Answer (score 68):

Ensure `position` is on your element and set the `z-index` to a value higher than the elements you want to cover.

```
element {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

It will probably require some more work than that but it's a start since you didn't post any code.

Comment: Thanks but what if i don't know the z-index of other elements. So lets say i am building a separate component and in my component i have a context menu implemented as a div and i want to make sure whoever is using my component no matter what the z-indexes are set for the div in his html for his stuff, i want to make sure my component should show the context menu ?

Comment: you need to use 9999 if you use jquery dlg and want to go higher than that.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that your markup looks like:

```
<div id="header" style="position: fixed;"></div>
<div id="content" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

Now both elements are positioned; in which case, the element at the bottom (in source order) will cover element above it (in source order).

Add a `z-index` on header; `1` should be sufficient.