# Always on top pop-up for Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, popup, google-chrome-os, always-on-top

I am trying to create a script so that when I activate it, it will open this link as a pop-up window that will stay on top: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ivES8N7VM2KrlDReeOS6JANCqzwwOxy802bQn4hNtr4/edit#gid=0

I am also trying to get this link to always stay on top. Any help I can get would be great, as I am fairly new to Google Scripts.

Comment: This question as it is now appears quite broad: what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I know how I want the command activated, I am just trying to make the script open that link as a pop-up. I would prefer it if it could stay on top of all the other windows. I have yet to try anything because I do not know where to start.

Comment: You need to make your link public.  This might be the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21386429/7215091).

Comment: You could embed it into a dialog.

Comment: How would I do that?

Also, it is now public.