# CSS "hover" menu being hidden by other hover-able text

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a popup that appears when the user hovers over text. A portion of text can be hovered over, which will make a small box appear below it containing additional text that's normally hidden.

The issue arises when there's another hover-able text portion where the box would display - the box is hidden behind it.

[image]

The Fiddle: [CSS Issue](https://jsfiddle.net/398gtshL/10/)

```css
.hovertext {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #CCEEFF;
  
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  
  z-index: 1;
}

.hovertext .hovertexttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #AAAAEE;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-line;
  
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  
  z-index: 2;
}

.hovertext:hover .hovertexttext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!-- this often happens on tables, where "hover" spots are below one another -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hovertext">
        hover here to see the issue
        <span class="hovertexttext">secret text!
        more secret text!
        even more secret text!
        but you can't see all of it...
        it's being blocked by the other element
        </span>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hovertext">
        i'm blocking the text aaaa
        <span class="hovertexttext">oh no</span>
       </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried:

- Removing the `position:absolute` tag from `hovertext` - this causes the entire "invisible" text to hide in the same area as the rest, pushing the rest of my HTML around.
- Removing `position:relative` tag in `hovertexttext` - HTML gets pushed around.
- Adjusting the `z-index` values, as well as removing them completely - doesn't have noticeable effect.
- Changing the `<div>` tags to `<span>`, and vice versa - doesn't have noticeable effect.

The hover menu is overlapping its parent `div` without any issues, so I'm led to believe it could overlap another `<div>` that's the same class, but I'm more or less stuck with how to proceed. Did I overlook something obvious?

Comment: Why do you have a z index for your relative elements?, Try removing the z index

Comment: @ImmortalDude I had read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21386429/7431860) and tried using `z-index` as a way to make the hover text text appear on top of the other elements. Removing it does not change or remove the problem, but I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues going on. Nested elements with conflicting indexes, display visible retains it's original sizing / nesting on the first measure arrange pass, and finally abusing box model semantic positioning. Hope this helps, cheers!

```css
.hovertext {
  background: #CCEEFF;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: help;
}

.hovertexttext {
  display: none;
  background: #AAAAEE;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-line;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.hovertext:hover .hovertexttext {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- this often happens on tables, where "hover" spots are below one another -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hovertext">
        hover here to see the issue
        <span class="hovertexttext">secret text!
        more secret text!
        even more secret text!
        but you can't see all of it...
        it's being blocked by the other element
        </span>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hovertext">
        i'm blocking the text aaaa
        <span class="hovertexttext">oh no</span>
       </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going for

Comment: Ya I got ya, but the z-index/positioning wasn't the only culprit, you set it up to get knocked out though cheers!

Comment: Accepted not just for an answer that works perfectly, but also for explaining what I was doing wrong. This is the first I've heard of the box model, and thanks to that, I've found a lot more material to read up on. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. You'll thank yourself later though since [css box model](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+box+model) literally is most of the presentation layer for most web things. Cheers